# Get the resource id from a drawable

Tags: android, resources, drawable, imagebutton

In xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/b_checkEv" 
    android:src="@drawable/img_huella" 
    ... />
```

In activity:

```
     ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b_checkEv);
     Drawable dr = ib.getDrawble();
```

I change dinamically the image of the ImageButton in code with ib.setDrawable().
Anybody knows how could I get the resouce id from the Drawable in order to know which image is set in the ImageButton in each moment?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just maintain an int that holds this value. ex. int currentImage = R.drawable.image;  ib.setDrawable(currentImage);

Answer (score 0):

The best way to control Android Buttons are Tags.

You can do "ib.setTag("image1.png")" and manage image data here.

Then you can do "String imageName = ib.getTag()" and get the image name.

Regards